# Apply custom function in list column to all elements of another list column and group result into list column of tibbles for plotting of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have two inputs: one is a tibble where one column is a list column with a custom function definition in it. That tibble also contains a variable 'id' indicating a specific set of parameters that generated the data. For each 'id', there are **n** rows in this tibble, each with a different variant of the custom function.

I want to apply that custom function to each element of another input. This is a list of lists (reference class instances actually, with one observation for each 'id' value), from which I need to extract a field 'z' and apply the custom function to. Hence each 'z' gets repeated **n** times and each time a different version of the custom function is applied to it.

The ultimate goal is to have a nested tibble that I can use in ggplot to create a separate plot for each 'id' value.

I have achieved this using the code below, but the result is very slow for big tables (>10M rows) because of the unnest-nest operations at the end to group the 'z' and 'zfn' columns into a list column of tibbles.

*The question is can I avoid that unnest-nest sequence and still end up with a  list column of tibbles that can be used in a ggplot call?*

```
library(tidyverse)

# First input, includes the list column of custom function definitions 'fndef' 
dfA <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:2, each = 3),
  fndef = list(function(x) x + 1, function(x) x + 2, function(x) x + 3, 
               function(x) x + 4, function(x) x + 5, function(x) x + 6)
  )

# Second input is a list of instances of a reference class from which we 
# are going to extract a field 'z' later on. 
# Since each instance matches 'id', the element 'z' needs to be repeated 
.Model <- setRefClass(
  "Model",

  fields = list(id = 'numeric',
                z = 'matrix')
  )

dfB <- list(.Model(id = 1, z = as.matrix(rnorm(10))), 
            .Model(id = 2, z = as.matrix(rnorm(10))))

# Combine inputs, extract 'z' from 'dfB', apply 'fndef' to each 'z' to return 'zfn' and 
# group both 'z' and 'zfn' into a tibble.
dfC <- dfA %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(z = map(.x = dfB, .f = ~.x$z)) %>%
  unnest(cols = data) %>%
  mutate(zfn = map2(.x = .$z, .y = .$fndef, .f = ~.y(.x))) %>%
  select(-fndef) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(z, zfn)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest()

# Ultimate goal is to plot, one plot per 'id'.
dfD <- dfC %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, id, ~ggplot(data = .x, mapping = aes(x = z, y = zfn)) +
                       geom_line()))
```

Comment: `tidyr 1.0.0`'s `nest()` and `unnest()` are too much slower than `nest_legacy()` and `unnest_legacy()`. This isn't a real solution to the problem but it is good idea to use `xxx_legacy()`.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 just tested the performance difference on the actual problem using `xxx_legacy()` instead of `nest-unnest`. It's ginormous, from >30mins down to <1sec! So it does solve the problem, but since those functions are retired, in some future version it will no longer work so I am still interested in ways to avoid the `unnest-nest` construct altogether.

Comment: Next version of `tidyr` would overcome this performance problem (see [https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/751]). But I agree with you, there is a value in looking for other way.